# Shopping cart is empty after adding product to cart in Magento on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.1. When I add a product to the cart and then click on checkout, it shows the shopping cart as empty.

I have cleared cache also but the problem still exist. I have increased the session cookie management up to 86400, but the problem is still there in the Chrome browser only. It is working fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug whether its posting data on Mage_Checkout_CartController  in addAction() Action. if it's not sending the data then you have to check for the form key. You can also check log files for more information,

Answer (score 0):

Please check your form key on the cart page. If it is not available then use the below code after form action.
Template path :

```
/app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml  
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```